# JS function/ajax only passing one parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have searched multiple threads on here and cannot find the answer.

I have a JS function that is supposed to post 2 parameters via ajax to a php page.  Here is the function:

```
function acceptbet(companyid, userid){

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "acceptbet.php",
        data: "companyid="+companyid+"&userid="+userid,
        success: function(msg){
        alert( companyid+userid );
        }       
    });
}
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
function acceptbet(companyid, userid){

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "acceptbet.php",
        data: {companyid:companyid,userid:userid},
        success: function(msg){
        alert( companyid+userid );
        }       
    });
}
```

No matter what I do, I can't get it to pass both parameters "userid" and "companyid" --- and the alert will only show the first one.  I tried switching the two parameters, and still only the first one is returnd.

I apologize if I'm making a rookie mistake, but I can't figure out how to pass both parameters to acceptbet.php.

Help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: here is the code for acceptbet.php:

```
$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$companyid=$_POST['companyid'];

$accepted=1;

$acceptbet = $connection->prepare("UPDATE user_bet set accepted=? where user_id=? and user_company_id=?");
$acceptbet->bind_param("iii",$accepted,$userid,$companyid);
$acceptbet->execute();
```

Comment: and when you do `alert(companyid, userid);`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy in the callback function.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Sorry maybe my question was a bit indiscernible. If you instead do, `alert(companyid, userid);` does it return as expected?

Comment: @Lenny instead of `alert( companyid+userid );`, try using `console.log(companyid, userid);` instead, and then check your JavaScript console. Usually that has more information.

Comment: are you sure that companyid and userid have a value can you please console.log(companyid);
console.log(userid );

before the ajax code.

Comment: what does var_dump( $_POST ); say in acceptbet.php

Comment: also, are you meaning to alert `companyid` and `userid`? shouldn't you check the `msg` instead?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `alert` takes one argument. The second one will be ignored if you use a comma instead of a plus here. What Lenny needs is `console.log`.

Comment: @Lenny alert( companyid+userid ) (guessing it is bot int) is a sum of the two parameter , thats why you only get one result, maybe possible that the second parameter has no value?

Comment: thanks for comments guys.  console.log correctly outputs the companyid and the userid.  do i have the right syntax with data: {companyid:companyid,userid:userid} ?  i can't figure out why it won't pass both parameters to acceptbet.php

Comment: Use the network tab in the Chrome debugger and you can see EXACTLY what the browser is sending to your server.  My guess is that the browser is doing exactly what it is supposed to and you aren't receiving/parsing the arguments properly in `acceptbet.php` on your server.

Comment: can you post the code of acceptbet.php for us to see how you try to access the data.

Comment: just posted the acceptbet.php code @Arrianezafe

Comment: @Lenny add this to acceptbet.php
 
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($_POST,true));
fclose($fp);

then check the test.txt value.

Comment: @Lenny tell us the value of test.txt thanks

Comment: @Arrianezafe I added what you posted, but nothing happened when I executed the script... is this supposed to open a notepad document with some contents?

Comment: @Lenny it will create a txt file with the filename of test.txt then all the $_POST data will be written inside of it. after that check if theres a test.txt inisde the folder of acceptbet.php folder.

Comment: thank you @Arrianezafe and all for your help.  I was able to determine that the ajax post was properly passing the two parameters thanks to your debugging tips.  I am ashamed to say it was a problem with my SQL  - my where clause was referencing incorrect records to be updated - so nothing was being updated.  Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 0):

My syntax was correct all along.  The comments that folks provided were VERY helpful for isolating the problem, which was in my SQL update - was expecting a record to update, but it was not - this was because my where clause was incorrect.  For reference, the syntax below should always work for passing multiple parameters in "data:" over ajax:

```
function acceptbet(companyid, userid){

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "acceptbet.php",
        data: {companyid:companyid,userid:userid},
        success: function(msg){
        alert( "success" );
        }       
    });
}
```